# React - Can't select individually a checkbox after selected them all using the "select all" checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React and i really struggle to spot what i'm doing wrong, i'm trying to populate my array positionChecked with the value of the checked checkbox to be able to POST a payload.

My "position" checkboxes  are added dynamically at my DOM next to the "select all" checkbox.

When i click on one of my position checkbox, i can see on the console that the value of that checkbox is added the positionChecked[] **BUT** the little blue checkbox is never triggered. The only way to trigger/untrigger it is to click on the "select all" checkbox.

The position checkboxes lost control on their states.

**App.js**

```
const items = [
    'Position 1',
    'Position 2',
    'Position 3'
];

class AppG extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            positionChecked: [],
            selectAll: false,
        };
        this.handleCheckboxSelection = this.handleCheckboxSelection.bind(this);
        this.handleSelectAll = this.handleSelectAll.bind(this);
    };

    handleCheckboxSelection(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newSelection = e.target.value;
        let newSelectionArray;
        if(this.state.positionChecked.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
            newSelectionArray = this.state.positionChecked.filter(s => s !== newSelection)
        } else {
            newSelectionArray = [...this.state.positionChecked, newSelection];
        }
        this.setState({ positionChecked: newSelectionArray}, () => console.log('position selection', this.state.positionChecked));
    };

    handleSelectAll(e) {
        this.setState({selectAll:e.target.checked}, () => console.log(this.state.selectAll));
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formPayload = {
            positionChecked: this.state.positionChecked,
        };
        console.log('Send this in a POST request:', formPayload);
        console.log(this.refs.checkbox.value);
    };

    createCheckboxes = (items) => (
        items.map(this.createCheckbox)
    );

    createCheckbox = item => (
        <Checkbox
            inline
            value={item}
            onChange={this.handleCheckboxSelection}
            checked={this.state.selectAll}
            key={'position'}
            type={'checkbox'}>
            {item}
        </Checkbox>
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Reporting by group</h1>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <Grid>
                        <Row className="show-grid">
                            <Col sm={3}>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={6}>
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref={form => this.form = form}>
                                    <InputGroup />
                                    <FormGroup style={styles}>
                                        <Checkbox
                                            inline
                                            onChange={this.handleSelectAll}
                                            checked={this.state.selectAll}
                                            key={'All'}
                                            value={'All'}
                                            type={'checkbox'}>All
                                        </Checkbox>
                                        {this.createCheckboxes(items)}
                                    </FormGroup>
                                    <Datepicker />
                                    <ButtonComponent type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                </form>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={3}>
                                <NavComponent/>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `checked={this.state.selectAll}` is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
createCheckbox = item => (
  <Checkbox
    inline
    value={item}
    onChange={this.handleCheckboxSelection}
    checked={this.state.selectAll || this.state.positionChecked.some(i => i === item)}
    key={'position'}
    type={'checkbox'}>
    {item}
  </Checkbox>
);
```

This will make the `checked` attribute true or false depending on whether the item is present in the `positionChecked` array or not.

Edit: Also, in order for this to work, you'll have to uncheck the 'Select All' checkbox (or better yet, force it to uncheck if any individual checkbox is manually unchecked).

Edit2: You should also consider changing the way you handle the 'Select All' checkbox. Instead of setting an individual boolean, it should add/remove all items in the `positionChecked` array.

Edit3: **handling 'Select All' differently**

If you break down the use case for both checkbox types ('select all' vs. individual selection), I'd say you want to achieve the following behavior:

- checking 'select all' checks all individual checkboxes
- unchecking 'select all' unchecks all individual checkboxes
- checking an individual box only checks that box and leaves others unchanged
- unchecking an individual box unchecks 'select all' if it was checked

This is how I would define both handlers to achieve this, using the state as you defined it originally:

```
handleCheckboxSelection(e) {
  const item = e.target.value;
  const positionChecked = this.state.positionChecked.some(i => i === item) ? this.state.positionChecked.filter(i => i === item) : [ ...this.state.positionChecked, item ]; 
  this.setState({ selectAll: false, positionChecked }, () => console.log(this.state));
};

handleSelectAll(e) {
  const selectAll = e.target.checked;
  const positionChecked = selectAll ? items : [];
  this.setState({ selectAll, positionChecked }, () => console.log(this.state));
};
```

The individual checkbox handler gets the item being checked/unchecked. If the item is present in the `this.state.positionChecked` array, a new array is returned where that item is filtered out, and if it's not present, a new array is returned where that item is added to the existing array. Then the state is set with this new array, and `selectAll` set to `false` (if `this.state.selectAll` was already `false`, we want to leave it that way, and if it was `true` we want to set it `false`, see use cases above ; setting it to `false` covers both scenarios).

The 'select all' handler is very straightforward. We set `selectAll` to reflect the checked status of the checkbox, and if it is checked, we set the `positionChecked` array to contain *all* items, and if it is unchecked, we set that array to be completely empty (again, see uses cases above).

Finally, with that being done, you can simplify the `checked` value in your `createCheckbox` method to the following:

```
checked={this.state.positionChecked.some(i => i === item)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, how can Select All "detect" the value of all the position checkbox present on the DOM ?

Comment: @user7698507 see Edit3 in my updated answer for how I would handle 'select all'.